# How to call functions with user input in main?

Tags: haskell, user-input, where-clause, program-entry-point

Libs.hs:

```
--TAKE INPUT OF USER CARD DETAILS AND SEPERATE EACH DIGIT AND INTO A LIST

getCard :: Integer -> [Integer]
getCard x
    | x <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = lst_numb : getCard pre_numb
      where
        (pre_numb, lst_numb) = x `divMod` 10

--TAKE SEPERATED DIGITS LIST AND REVERSE

cardNumber :: Integer -> [Integer]
cardNumber = reverse . getCard


--DOUBLE EVERY OTHER NUMBER STARTING FROM THE RIGHT (TO THE LEFT OF CHECK NUMBER)

doubleNumber :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleNumber [] = []
--doubleNumber (x:y:xs) = 2*x : y : doubleNumber xs //This is the partially working function for Q2
doubleNumber (x:y:xs)
    | validFormat (x:y:xs) == True = 2*x : y : doubleNumber xs
    |otherwise = []


--CHECKS ISSUER ID IS VALID & CARD NUMBER IS 16 DIGITS LONG

validFormat :: [Integer] -> Bool
validFormat  x
    | x == [] = False
    | (head x == 3 || head x == 4 || head x == 5 || head x == 6) && length x == 16 = True
    | otherwise = False

--ADDITION OF ALL DIGITS INSIDE THE LIST
addNumbers :: [Integer] -> Integer
addNumbers xs = sum xs

--SUBTRACT NINE FROM DOUBBLE DIGIT NUMBERS

subDoubles :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
subDoubles [] = []
subDoubles (x:xs)
    | x > 9 = x - 9 : subDoubles xs
    | otherwise =  x : subDoubles xs

--COMBINED FUNCTION TO VALIDATE A CREDIT CARD NUMBER

validateCard :: Integer -> Bool
validateCard x = compute x `mod` 10 == 0
    where
      compute :: Integer -> Integer
      compute = addNumbers . subDoubles . doubleNumber . cardNumber

--DISPLAY USER MSG IF CARD IS VALID OR NOT
isValid card
  | card == True = "This is a valid credit card!"
  | otherwise = "This card is invalid"
```

Main.hs:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter a credit card number:"
    input <- getLine
    let card = read input :: Integer
    isValid . validateCard card
```

I have Haskell project that validates credit card numbers from a users input (as above in Libs.hs):

I can use the validateCard function in ghci with numbers and it produces true or false. I want the user to input a credit card number in the Main.hs file and be given a string promoting whether their input is valid or invalid however, i don't know if i am correctly calling the validateCard function in my main. Could someone please explain where i am going wrong with my approach?
Been at this for a while so any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
The code i uploaded was code i was trying out but this is the initial way in which i attempted and it was not working correctly

Comment: Use `getLine` to get the user input, then run your functions on that. You'll need to convert it from a string to an integer file first.

Comment: Your last line `isValid.card <- validateCard` is not syntactically correct Haskell. Think of `<-` as being approximately equivalent to `:=`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have uploaded the wrong code for my main.hs, that is the way i originally attempted it however still faced issues

Comment: @PaulJohnson apologise that was not what i meant to upload, this edited  post gives an error when matching expected types

Comment: Voting to close, post lacks focus.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up precedence rules in:

```
isValid . validateCard card
```

This parses as

```
isValid . (validateCard card)
```

but that doesn't work because `validateCard card` isn't a function. You need to write one of these instead:

```
isValid . validateCard $ card
isValid $ validateCard card
```

Comment: Since `isValid` returns a string, this isn't valid. Since the output from `isValid` seems to be a message intended for the user, the most natural thing would be to do `putStrLn $ isValid $ validateCard card`

Comment: That's a reasonable guess, but I just dealt with the expression because I wasn't sure what was to be done with the result. You're right, of course, that _something_ must be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Robin Zigmond said this in his comment, but you're looking for `getLine`:

```
getLine :: IO string
```

From `main`, you will use it like this:

```
main = do
    input <- getLine
```

Comment: I am able to get the user input using getLine however i do not know how to use `input` with my function `validateCard`